# Which version of libstdc++.so.6 to use?

Tags: c++, solaris, libstdc++

I'm using a third party shared library (libsw_api.so) on Solaris, which when I try to load, produces the following error:

```
fatal: relocation error: file libsw_api.so:
symbol _ZNKSt9bad_alloc4whatEv: referenced symbol not found
The program exited with error code 1
```

When I run ldd on libsw_api.so, all references seem to be fulfilled, specifically the C++ standard library which points to libstdc++.so.6.0.3:

```
glispa02(fostopr)$ ldd libsw_api.so
...
libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6
...
glispa02(fostopr)$ ls -l /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          18 Jun 21  2010 /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.3
```

However that library does not export _ZNKSt9bad_alloc4whatEv,

```
glispa02(fostopr)$ nm /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep bad_alloc                          
[7592]  |    752340|      64|FUNC |GLOB |0    |2653   |_ZNSt9bad_allocD0Ev
[7324]  |    752284|      56|FUNC |GLOB |0    |2652   |_ZNSt9bad_allocD1Ev
[8077]  |    752228|      56|FUNC |GLOB |0    |2651   |_ZNSt9bad_allocD2Ev
[7519]  |    356736|      76|FUNC |GLOB |0    |473    |_ZSt17__throw_bad_allocv
[7341]  |    983588|      12|OBJT |WEAK |0    |3842   |_ZTISt9bad_alloc
[6569]  |    777008|      13|OBJT |WEAK |0    |3317   |_ZTSSt9bad_alloc
[7299]  |    983568|      20|OBJT |WEAK |0    |3841   |_ZTVSt9bad_alloc
```

What could be the problem? Wrong version? I'm not really good with C++ on Unix so I'ld appreciate any help.

Could this SPARC32PLUS vs. SPARC mismatch be the cause of the problem?

```
glispa02(fostopr)$ file libsw_api.so        
libsw_api.so:   ELF 32-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required,    dynamically linked, not stripped
glispa02(fostopr)$ file /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.3 
/usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.3:        ELF 32-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
```

My system:

```
glispa02(fostopr)$ cat /etc/release                    
                  Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC
       Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                    Use is subject to license terms.
                       Assembled 16 September 2009
glispa02(fostopr)$ uname -a
SunOS glispa02 5.10 Generic_141444-09 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
```

Comment: I wonder whether one libstdc++ has `bad_alloc::what` inlined from headers instead, and libsw_api has been compiled against a different libstdc++.

Comment: Maybe with different optimization settings the OP's source will compile with `what()` inlined? Just a wild guess...

Answer (score 2):

Hi I'm also upgrading these files, I noticed that I should be using the libstdc++.so.6.0.9 file that comes with the distribution rather than the one in /usr/sfw/lib/

Answer (score 1):

If you use pvs on the `libstdc++.so.6` file, it will give you a bunch of entries matching: `GLIBCXX`, if you don't have an entry matching `GLIBCXX_3.4.9`, then the symbol `bad_alloc::what` is not in that library i.e. the library is older than the dependent object `libsw_api.so`

If this is the case then you probably need a newer version of libstdc++ - it would come with a newer version of g++

Comment: pvs output: `libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3);` and `libc.so.1 (SUNW_1.22, SUNWprivate_1.1);`. I will try to upgrade g++, thanks!

Comment: I think I understand your comment better now, you want to know which interfaces `libstdc++.so.6` provides, not what it depends upon, right? When I do `pvs -d /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6` I get no output at all. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same issue.

The cause is we export the wrong LD_LIBRARY_PATH
So that our shared library link to the original gcc's library (3.3) instead of our compiler (gcc 4.4).

Fix the linker problem should solve the issue